# SSRS Report Enlarge Grouping + / - toggle

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way to make the + / - grouping toggle larger? We are creating a report that will be viewed and controlled from further away and it's hard to see it.

I have searched everywhere for an answer, I have found a lot of info on expand all functions but nothing on enlarging the toggle itself.

I did find a workaround but it's not ideal, we set the font really small and used the zoom to make the report bigger which made the toggle bigger, but the resolution is not as clear.